# Add a class to all images in article dynamically

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin

I'm trying to build a plugin that adds a class to all images in my articles. So far I have the following code:

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');
class plgContentAddImageClass extends JPlugin
{
    public function __construct(&$subject, $params)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $params);
    }
    public function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $offset = 0)
    {
        // Article Content
        $content = &$article->text;
        // Find images and add a class
    }
?>
```

But I'm stuck as to how I can find images in the content and add a class to them. Also, the images might have a class already, in that case I want to add a new one to the existing classes.

**Edit:**
I have a plugin that watermarks any image with a certain class, but because the site already has lots of images, I would like to add the class to the images dynamically instead of going through each `<img>` tag on the site and add the classes.

I'm aware that I can target all images with CSS, it just doesn't help in this case.

Comment: I know the question is how to build a plugin but did you consider that you can add a class to all your images with only CSS ?

Comment: @SébastienGicquel: Can you elaborate on this? How he could add a class with only CSS?

Comment: @FFrewin Sorry, i'm confused, I made a mistake, he can't add a class only with CSS. I said "add a class" but i wanted to say "target' : if he wants to add a class to all images in articles, he can easily target all images with CSS (.article img {/*code*/}) But i understand that he asked how to make a plugin. Maybe he should explain a bit more what he is trying to do in order to find the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've updated the question with an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load the content into a `DOMDocument()`, and manipulate it.

```
<?php
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');
class plgContentAddImageClass extends JPlugin
{
    public function __construct(&$subject, $params)
    {
        parent::__construct($subject, $params);
    }
    public function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $offset = 0)
    {
        // Article Content
        $content = &$article->text;
        // Find images and add a class
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $images                  = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach($images as $image) {
            // the existing classes already on the images
            $existing_classes   = $image->getAttribute('class');
            // the class you want to add
            $new_class          = ' yourclass';
            // the existing classes plus the new class
            $class_names_to_add = $existing_classes . $new_class;
            $image->setAttribute('class', $class_names_to_add);
        }
        // $dom now contains a complete HTML source, remove unnecessary tags
        $content = preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $dom->saveHTML()));
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I think that you're missing a `$dom->loadHtml($content)` in there somewhere.

Comment: Yes, good observation (and silly mistake)... thank you, fixed it now.

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine. What is the `@` before `$dom->loadHTML` mean, and why are you using `$dom->loadHtml(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));` instead of just  `$dom->loadHtml($content)`

Comment: The `@` is a PHP error [control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), forcing any possible error to be ignored. `loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'))` will force UTF-8 encoding, it might not be necessary, but as I often work with Norwegian characters (æ, ø, å), I add this to avoid garbled letters (like `Ã¼Â¥Ã³`).

Answer (score 4):

Why would you want to do this?

You can easily target all images in an article with css without using a plugin, all you need is a bit of css;

```
.view-article img { // My awesome styles here ;}
```

Targets all images in your articles and doesn't add any the overhead, or complexity, a plugin would. The simplest way is always the best way.

Maintainable, scalable, secure.

Comment: Thank you, but in this case I need to add the class because I'm using a plugin that adds a watermark to images with a certain class.

Comment: Still don't see why you would need to add a class dynamically. If your plugin can find images in articles it can then just add the watermark to those images. If you want it to only target images with a certain class, then your plugin doesn't need to add that class dynamically, does it?